# aggregate in MongoDB group on date-exceeding timeframe

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, timespan

I have scheduled tasks(parent) which start in the evening and runs an amount of jobs(children) which can be successful or not. I want to know the success rate for each executed task

Each document of collection jobs_per_task_per_day should contain

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "task" : ObjectId("52b31753d925d5b057000001"),
        "year" : 2013,
        "month" : 12,
        "day" : 22
    },
        "successful" : 12,
        "unsuccessful" : 0,
        "task" : ObjectId("52b31753d925d5b057000001")
}
```

However, in my current aggregation script, I group per date. This gives an inaccuracy since the execution of an task can endure the whole night. a job started at 01-02-2014 02:00 is part of the task started at 01-01-2014. not 01-02-2014.

If the job ran after midnight but before 12:00 afternoon the next day, it should be counted to the document of a day earlier. **The task itself does not have a date, since it is executed repeatedly with cron.**

A Job:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b3751dd925d507db013f0e"),
    "started_at" : ISODate("2013-12-19T22:37:17.900Z"),
    "successful" : true,
    "task_id" : ObjectId("52b31f8bd925d5b057000005")
     }
```

A scheduled task:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b31f8bd925d5b057000005"),
    "schedule" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("52b31784d925d5b057000002"),
        "cron" : "30 21 * * *",
        "name" : "Foo Import",
        "worker_class" : "TaskWorker"
    }
}
```

My current script:

```
    var scheduled_tasks = db.tasks.find({
    schedule: {
      $exists: true
    }
  }).toArray()

scheduled_tasks.forEach(function(task) {
      var results_total = db.jobs.aggregate({
          $match: {
            task_id: task._id
          }
        },

        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              year: {
                $year: "$started_at"
              },
              month: {
                $month: "$started_at"
              },
              day: {
                $dayOfMonth: "$started_at"
              },
              task: "$task_id"
            },

            successful: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: ["$successful", 0, 1]
              }
            },
            unsuccessful: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: ["$successful", 1, 0]
              }
            },
            task: {
              $first: "$task_id"
            },

          }
        }, {
          $project: {
            successful: 1,
            unsuccessful: 1,
            task: 1
          }
        }, {
          $sort: {
            date: -1
          }
        }
      );
      db.jobs_per_task_per_day.insert(results_total.result)
    });
```

to group on timespan instead of date i tried to change it to:

```
 $group: { 

  _id: {
    task: "$task_id",
    year: { $year: "$started_at" },
    month: { $month: "$started_at" },
    day: { 
      $cond: [
        {$lt: [{$hour: "$started_at"}, 12]},
        {$dayOfMonth: "$started_at"} -1, 
        {$dayOfMonth: "$started_at"}
      ]
    }      
  }
```

However this did not return the desired result, and i'm doubting if it should be in the group operator.

Any help on this would really be appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you shouldn't need to worry about dates at all. Given documents for each job in a task, you just count the number of successful/unsuccessful jobs for the given task using a common task reference in the job documents - where does the date come in? Is a job unsuccessful if it runs longer than noon the day after the task was run? I think we might need more detail in the question to understand how the date factors in here, given that all you say you want is the number of successful jobs for a task.

Comment: Every time the same task is performed, new job documents are created. Lets say one unique task has 400 jobs. 100 the first time it was performed, 100 the second time it was performed etc. All those jobs have the same parent_id, so the only way to group them as belonging to the same batch is by date. No problem there if a task would end before the end of the day. I could simply group by date. Problem is that the tasks run at night so one part of the batch is performes before midnight and another part after midnight

Comment: That sounds like 4 tasks, perhaps all of the same type, not one task.